# Undefined method manipulate! - carrierwave with minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I am using carrierwave with minimagick to upload an image and crop it to a square. However I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'manipulate!' for #<Class:0x692db10>
```

it seems to make no sense, as i have included the correct class, and that part works fine. Heres my current uploader class.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  @@sizes = {
    "2000" => 2048,
    "1500" => 1500,
    "1000" => 1024,
    "500" => 512,
    "250" => 256,
    "100" => 128
  }

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :square do
    manipulate! do |img|
      size = img.dimensions.min
    end
    process resize_to_fill: [size, size]
  end
end
```

to be clear, we are talking about the `:square` version. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `manipulate!` belongs to [`RMagick` adapter](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/#using-rmagick), for [MiniMagick](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/#using-minimagick) you should use something like `mogrify`.

Indeed, there's such method, but you're trying to use it in a class scope, while it's an instance method. There's a [bunch of useful class methods](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb#L68-L88) you can use already.

If you still need `manipulate!`, make something like this:

```
process :radial_blur => 10

def radial_blur(amount)
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.radial_blur(amount)
    img = yield(img) if block_given?
    img
  end
end
```

Comment: but the method _is_ in the `CarrierWave::MiniMagic` module

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb#L296